# Which of the following words will be suitable to name the bonus? recommendation, recommending and recommender

Tags: word-choice

The following is the translation draft of a part of description about a bet game website.

> In this bet game website, a member can share a recommending link of a
>   bet game (or a code added after the original link), and if he/she
>   attracts the most credits placed from others than other recommenders
>   in a game, he/she will win some bonus.
>
> In "badge collection", there is a series called "Best recommender".
>   It counts on times of sharing a recommending link and attracting
>   the most credits placed from others in a game.

"referral link" has already been used to refer to the link used to build downlines. To make it clear and not ambiguous, I hope to use different words; that is to say, "referral bonus" and "recommendation(?) bonus".

Regarding the word family of recommend, I would like to ask word choice as follows.

1. Which one is better when name the bonus?

   recommendation bonus

   recommending bonus

   recommender bonus

˙

2. Which one is better when name the link? (PS. The "referral link" has already been used to refer to the link used to build downlines.)

   recommendation link

   recommending link

   recommender link

˙

3. Is the name "Best recommender" good? Won't it be ambiguous with "best recommender system"?

˙

Comment: [which words **are** suitable, general statement, not will]

Comment: It's probably confusing to have different things called e.g. referral bonus, recommender bonus, recommendation bonus, and recommending bonus. Give them more descriptive names e.g. "game recommendation bonus", "customer recommendation bonus", "link recommendation bonus", "most recommendations bonus". Site users are unlikely to fully comprehend that a recommendation bonus is different to a recommending bonus or recommender bonus.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer *Recommendation bonus* for 1 + 2.

For 3 maybe you could go for something like *Most recommendations*.

*Best recommender* feels a little odd.

Comment: *Recommender* is certainly a much less common word than the others.

Answer (score 0):

For what little it's worth, I like *recommender bonus* for a bonus that goes to the most successful recommender, and *recommendation link* for a link expressing a recommendation.

(I don't know what you mean by *downline*.)